# glRotatef not updating

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I want to rotate a Quad along 360 degrees with the code below).  I am varying "input" on another procedure (Range = 0 to 1).

Despite "input" changing correctly, I can not seem to update rotation of a quad on screen - It remains stuck at the first angle, e.g. 180 if input is 0.5.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, height, 0);

    gl.glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);

    gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glTranslatef(width/2, height/2, 0.0f);
      gl.glRotatef(360 * input, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    bgQuad.setX(0);
    bgQuad.setY(0);

    bgQuad.draw(gl);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

move `popMatrix` to after `bgQuad.draw(gl);`:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, height, 0);

    gl.glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);

    gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glTranslatef(width/2, height/2, 0.0f);
      gl.glRotatef(360 * input, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


      bgQuad.setX(0);
      bgQuad.setY(0);

      bgQuad.draw(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

`glPopMatrix` resets the matrix back to the most recent saved matrix and throws away the current matrix.

Comment: I have tried this and same issue;  once the rotation angle has be set once, it does not seem to update, despite input changing.

Comment: Can you give us the first few (let's say 5) values of 'input'?

Comment: Yes, the value starts at 0, and increments by 0.1, to a maximum of 1, then resets to 0 again.  I can confirm that the "input" is correctly increasing on each call to onDrawFrame.